# How to get menu items from Adobe Illustrator interface?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-scripting, actionscript, extended-scripting

There are many drop-down menus in the top of the Adobe Illustrator window. I would like to have a way to get a tree of these commands with their functions to cal in the script.

For example, for this menu

```
Edit
---
Undo
Redo
Cut
Copy
Paste
Paste in front
Paste in back
Paste in place
etc.
```

I would like to have a list somewhat like this: (by commands I mean actionscript commands)

```
Edit: {
    Undo: {-command for calling undo-}
    Redo: {-commamd for calling redo-}
    Paste: {-command for calling pasting-}
}

etc.
```

I wonder if it's possible to do this without doing it all by hand? What should I look for?

is something like this still possible? http://kasyan.ho.ua/tips/indesign_script/all/open_menu_item.html

Comment: This seems to be an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) You might be better off asking us about what you're trying to achieve, rather than what you think you might have to do in order to achieve it.

Comment: Theres no wayto call all menuitems as theres no script interface for all of them. Most notably you can not really call boolean operations on items easily via script

Comment: Menu items do not always equate to a single script command – sometimes they do different things depending on the current selection or other parameters. So you can’t really, beyond linking them to the invoke method (which allows you to explicitly invoke a menu item).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure this is what you are after...

However, Adobe does provide shortcut maps in the **[help files](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/default-keyboard-shortcuts.html)**...

| Shortcuts | Windows | macOS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Undo | Ctrl + Z | Command + Z |
| Redo | Shift + Ctrl + Z | Shift + Command + Z |
| Cut | Ctrl + X | Command + X |
| Copy | Ctrl + C | Command + C |
| Paste | Ctrl + V | Command + V |
| Paste in front | Ctrl + F | Command + F |
| Paste at back | Ctrl + B | Command + B |
| Paste in place | Shift + Ctrl + B | Shift + Command + B |
| Paste on all artboards | Alt + Shift + Ctrl + B | Option + Shift + Command + B |
| Check spelling | Ctrl + I | Command + I |
| Open the Color Settings dialog box | Shift + Ctrl + K | Shift + Command + K |
| Open the Keyboard Shortcuts dialog box | Alt + Shift + Ctrl + K | Option + Shift + Command + K |
| Open the Preferences dialog box | Ctrl + K | Command + K |

If you want *text* merely copy/paste from the help page.

Adobe does offer downloadable jpg images with the listings as well...

[image]

https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/default-keyboard-shortcuts.html

They do also offer similar for Adobe Animate: https://helpx.adobe.com/animate/kb/animate-keyboard-shortcuts.html